# Considerations when signing up for a Salesforce trial using Google Authentication?

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, authentication, login, google-apps

I am signing up for a Salesforce trial, and was surprised to see that one can use a Google login to start the trial:

[image]

Before I take this step, I want to understand the consequences. Here are some of my questions/concerns:

1. Will I only be able to login with Google if I sign-up with a trial using Google authentication?
2. Will I get to pick a username (i.e. me@myco.com) or will it be some strange "key" or long auto-generated string?
3. If you go to https://login.salesforce.com there is no Login with Google button, so how does one login if you initially login with Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Will I only be able to login with Google if I sign-up with a trial
   using Google authentication?

   **No, They read only your First Name, Last Name and basic info which is required to fill right section of this signup page using google,facebook.**
2. Will I get to pick a username (i.e.
   me@myco.com) or will it be some strange "key" or long auto-generated
   string?

   **As you know Salesforce username is unique across the org so if your gmail id is not registered with Salesforce they will set that as your username otherwise it will ask you to put unique username.**
3. If you go to https://login.salesforce.com there is no Login
   with Google button, so how does one login if you initially login
   with Google?

   **No you can't, if you want SSO. you need to setup my domain and setup SSO yourself.**